# Down Sampling Technique for LibSVM

Tags: weka, libsvm

I have an unbalanced training data which I am going to use for training SVM classifier. I have tried out several techniques for handling unbalanced data such as cost sensitive learning and sampling techniques. For sampling techniques I need to find methods for up sampling and downsampling instead random methods. What are the techniques that can be used for up sampling and down sampling? I am using weka and LibSVM for classification.

Answer (score 1):

For up sampling most frequently used method is SMOTE. Here are some useful URLs,
SMOTE description - http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume16/chawla02a-html/node6.html
Weka SMOTE filter -http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/SMOTE/weka/filters/supervised/instance/SMOTE.html